# How to get a ESL Souvenir?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

While the title says it all, there is a few things that I need to mention

1. I've already sync up my twitch account with my steam.
2. I've already know that the drop chance is 50% after every match.
3. I've been afk watching the stream overnight
4. I've already know that the case only drops at the announced time.

But still, no luck for me. Didn't get any case drops.
You may ask in the comment section if you need more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very slight chance to drop a case during a match.

If you look at the numbers sometimes , there are arround 30.000 people watching and only ~ 300 get drops during the stream.

To increase your chance watch the match in Csgo and in Twitch simultanious.

Still the chance to get a drop is very small , since that's what makes these cases so expensive.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for telling and correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

You only get souvenirs during during announced times. Generally, they only turn the souvenir drops on during the actual ESL/Valve major tournaments (not the qualifier events).

Comment: Yes, I know it too but I forgot to state it in my post. Sorry. But still no cases.